# Gift card code not working in the Safari browser

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, gift-card

I am using Magento Enterprise version 2.4.5, and there is an issue, the gift card code is not working in the Safari browser, but the same is working in other browsers like Google Chrome & Microsoft Edge. Anyone has any idea, what the issue will be?

Any help is appreciated !!!